# Eclipse EGit auto commit/push

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, egit

How to configure EGit plugin in Eclipse to auto-commit to local repository and auto-push to GitHub whenever a file is changed (i.e. on every build)?

That would be much better than commit/push manually.

Comment: Uhm, many people will strongly disagree with that ;)

Comment: Apart from laziness, why would you actually ever, ever, ever want to do this?

Comment: @Zavior To track every change I made (i.e. Imagine that I deleted a file and later on I want to restore that file).

Comment: Tracking changes are what a VCS are for; but configuring for autocommit is probably not desirable either. Are you really sure that you'll have the discipline to only build on commit frontiers?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restore changes you accidentially did, have a look at the local history in Eclipse. It already records that for you.

Comment: I would advise you next time to describe the _problem_, not the _solution_ you imagine. :)